# Pyspark - Loop and for in Range - get the last value only

Tags: python, loops, apache-spark, pyspark, range

I want to merge two columns of a dataframe two by two so I used the "for in range" function. However, I just, when displaying, the last result.

How can I get, in a dataframe, all the results?

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, col

df = spark.read.load('abfss://......')

for item in range(1,21,2): 
   df2=df.select(concat_ws("/",df[item:item],df[item+1:item+1]).alias(df.columns[item:item]))
   
display(df2)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use python `itertools.zip_longest` to group columns by 2 and concat : `df.select(*[F.concat_ws("/", *c).alias(c[0]) for c in zip_longest(*([iter(df.columns[1:21])]*2))])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list indexing returns nothing because the start and end indices are the same, and you're overwriting the dataframe `df2` in each iteration of the for loop. Try the below approach instead:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws

df2 = df.select([
    concat_ws('/', df.columns[i], df.columns[i+1]).alias(df.columns[i])
    for i in range(1,21,2)
])
```